# Call a string value to create a meta tag?

Tags: string, echo, meta-tags, whmcs

I need to create meta tags for the seo of my website.
I am using WHMCS and a custom template

Any page is compiled through the header.tpl, footer.php page1.tpl and page1.php pages

What I tried was to add
">
to header.tpl which does add the line of code to the "output source"
and I added
$pgDesc = 'Any custom description';
to the page1.php

Somehow the echo $pgDesc does not call the value correct

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your metatags to header.tpl. And that's all. You can get your title/desctiption/keywords strings from various sources: whmcs variables, translation strings, and even some db.

See http://docs.whmcs.com/Seo